# Passing two parameters using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters

I want to pass two parameters from one page to other page. I am able to pass single parameter. when it comes to two parameters, i get the error http 404 could not found. [My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sMfN.png)

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiHft.png)
What I want to achieve here is, I want to share trainer id and title to the next page. 
When i put  , it gives me error like HTTP 404 .

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the controller code for DetailedTrainerView? It would make it easier to see what the issue is.

Comment: Just added. Would like to pass two parameters to next page. How can i use query string in view?

Comment: Is DetailedTrainerView action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe replace your hyperlink with

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DetailedTrainerView","CategoryTrainer",new
                                        {
                                            id=@item.TrainerId,
                                            title=@item.Title
                                        })>Link text</a>
```

Comment: Nice example, I practice doing the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. Working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
href="<%: Url.Action("DetailedTrainerView", "CategoryTrainer", new { trainerID = @item.TrainerID, title = @item.Title }) %>"
```

and make sure your action method has same parameter name and sequence.